No FAF on IAP chart other than VOR or NDB?
I know no FAF depicted is common thing for some VOR IAP or NDB IAP. I'm just curious, other than VOR approach or NDB approach, are there any IAPs that does not have FAF in the profile view?

If there is no FAF, the final segment of the approach begins when you are established on the final track after a procedure turn or racetrack.

Note that the terminology for FAF (fix) and FAP (point) differs between ICAO and the FAA. See here for more details.

The only approaches that do not have a FAF would be one that has a procedure turn and no way to identify the FAF.
In ages past, the pilot would navigate to the VOR or NDB which was on the field and commence the approach (IAF) from that point.
As they turned inbound, it was considered passing the FAF.
There shouldn't be any RNAV (GPS) or other apporaches like this anymore.

why there is no way to identify the FAF as it has a procedure turn ( like a teardrop turn or back course?)

PT inbound is considered the FAF.  The navaids available for use on these procedures do not allow a pilot to positively identify a waypoint inbound.  There is most likely no DME available, and no other navaid expect the primary to use to positively identify another point.
